# How to set specific point to a node in MSAGL

Tags: c#, graph, msagl

I'm trying to draw some graph using the Microsoft's MSAGL. Here I have some nodes, but is there a way to set their position using Points?

I need to place up to hundred points to specific places in this picture and let the algorithm to route everything.

For example:

```
mainGraph = new Microsoft.Msagl.Drawing.Graph("mainGraph");
mainGraph.AddNode(new Node("NODE"));

GViewer1.Graph = mainGraph;

mainGraph.FindNode("NODE").GeometryNode.Center = new Point(10, 10); // <- Doesn't do anything.
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to define the node's center using a Microsoft.Msagl.Core.Geometry Point, like below:

```
graph.FindNode("Node0").GeometryNode.Center = new Microsoft.Msagl.Core.Geometry.Point(100, 100);
```

Comment: For me, setting the node center and adding another line with `GViewer1.Graph = mainGraph;` moved the node to the desired position, but all edges pointing to it still pointed to the old node's position. How to move the node and still have the edges pointing to it correctly?